# Getting SQLException when writing dataset having string columns to teradata

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, teradata

I am getting below given error when trying to write dataset from spark to teradata while having some string data in dataset:

```
2018-01-02 15:49:05 [pool-2-thread-2] ERROR c.i.i.t.spark2.algo.JDBCTableWriter:115 - Error in JDBC operation:
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: Data Type "TEXT" does not match a Defined Type name.
      at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:308)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:114)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:385)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.doNonPrepExecuteUpdate(TDStatement.java:602)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeUpdate(TDStatement.java:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.createTable(JdbcUtils.scala:805)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
```

How can I ensure that the data gets properly written into teradata.

I am reading csv file from HDFS into dataset and then trying to write the same to Teradata using DataFrameWriter. I using below given code for this:

```
ds.write().mode("append")
            .jdbc(url, tableName, props);
```

I am using spark 2.2.0 and Teradata is 15.00.00.07
I am getting somewhat similar issues when I tried writing in to Nettezza while in DB2 the I am able write but string values are getting replaced with .
Is there any kind of option required while writing to these databases..?

Comment: can you provide your code where exception occured

Comment: What TD version are you using?  Maybe the "TEXT" data type isn't supported.  Try using a VARCHAR or BLOB data type instead.  And please post the code (SQL, data sets, etc.) that generated this error.

Comment: There is no `TEXT` data type in Teradata in any version.

Comment: I have added the code snippet from where this error is being generated. Also from the same code I am able to write to oracle, sqlserver and postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by implementing custom JDBCDialect for Teradata.
The same approach can be used to address similar issues with other datasources like Netezza, DB2, Hive, etc.

To do so, you need to extend 'JdbcDialect' class and register it:

```
public class TDDialect extends JdbcDialect {

private static final Map<String, Option<JdbcType>> dataTypeMap = new HashMap<String, Option<JdbcType>>();

static {
    dataTypeMap
            .put("int", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("INTEGER",
                    java.sql.Types.INTEGER)));
    dataTypeMap.put("long",
            Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("BIGINT", java.sql.Types.BIGINT)));
    dataTypeMap.put("double", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply(
            "DOUBLE PRECISION", java.sql.Types.DOUBLE)));
    dataTypeMap.put("float",
            Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("FLOAT", java.sql.Types.FLOAT)));
    dataTypeMap.put("short", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("SMALLINT",
            java.sql.Types.SMALLINT)));
    dataTypeMap
            .put("byte", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("BYTEINT",
                    java.sql.Types.TINYINT)));
    dataTypeMap.put("binary",
            Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("BLOB", java.sql.Types.BLOB)));
    dataTypeMap.put("timestamp", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("TIMESTAMP",
            java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP)));
    dataTypeMap.put("date",
            Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("DATE", java.sql.Types.DATE)));
    dataTypeMap.put("string", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("VARCHAR(255)",
            java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)));
    dataTypeMap.put("boolean",
            Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("CHAR(1)", java.sql.Types.CHAR)));
    dataTypeMap.put("text", Option.apply(JdbcType.apply("VARCHAR(255)",
            java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)));
}

/***/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public boolean canHandle(String url) {
    return url.startsWith("jdbc:teradata");
}

@Override
public Option<JdbcType> getJDBCType(DataType dt) {
    Option<JdbcType> option = dataTypeMap.get(dt.simpleString().toLowerCase());
    if(option == null){
        option = Option.empty();
    }
    return option;
}

}
```

Now you can register this using below code snippet before calling any Action on spark:

```
JdbcDialects.registerDialect(new TDDialect());
```

With some datasources, like Hive for example, You may need to override one more method to avoid NumberFormatExceptions or some similar exceptions:

```
@Override
public String quoteIdentifier(String colName) {
    return colName;
}
```

Hope this will help anyone facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me, can you please try once and let me know?

```
Point to be noted:
***Your hive table must be in Text format as storage. It should not be ORC.
Create the schema in Teradata before writing it from your pyspark notebook.***




df = spark.sql("select * from dbname.tableName")
properties = {
"driver": "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver",
"user": "xxxx",
"password": "xxxxx"
}

df.write.jdbc(url='provide_url',table='dbName.tableName', properties=properties)
```